# How to use multiple servers concurrently in Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-jms, spring-kafka

I have to use kafka as a queue but want to use multiple servers for concurrent processing, and should not receive duplicates. For example,

P1 and P2 are sending the data to message partition P.
C1, C2 and C3 are listening to partition P so that order can be maintained.

In this case, only one node is active and this is a time-consuming job, so we get a bottleneck. Since we want the order to be maintained, we don't want to use multiple partitions.

The option I have currently is to make the long running job into async so that it can do the bare minimum and leave rest for async. This is very difficult to achieve in our use case.

Another option is to use multiple partitions and handle the ordering manually, again not very preferable.

The final option is to use it as a topic and deal with duplicity manually.

None of the options is perfect, and what I want is use like spring-jms shareable topic connection, where it register all the subscriber but send the message to only one among it in the round-robin. This doesn't guarantee the strict order, but my test still found much better ordering than kafka with multiple partitions.

Do you have any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is the way how Kafka works.

All the consumers in the same `consumer group` is subscribed to the topic, but only one of them can consume. If that fails somehow, the rebalance happens on broker and some other consumer in the group will pick the event stream from the partition.

This way we reach the best consuming from Kafka performance. If your logic is slow downstream, that already not a Kafka responsibility.

So, *round-robin* consuming isn't possible with raw Kafka by its nature.

You can achieve that really via shifting the data to some other messaging broker. The same JMS or RabbitMQ.

With the Spring Integration and its persistent `QueueChannel` support your can implement round robing as well.

But I'm afraid there is nothing for that in the Apache Kafka per se.
And yes, Spring Kafka isn't going to break the contract and introduce something on the matter. Just because such an approach would cause continuous rebalancing.

Comment: thanks for the input Artem, I was just checking if there is any possibility with some setting in kafka itself.

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can simulate fanouts in Kafka by adding more partitions to a topic. That way messages are load balanced across multiple consumers in the same group. Ideally, you would want to have matching number of partitions to the number of consumers that you'd run within the group to maximize throughput.

Comment: Listen, the story is about exactly one partition. Even if you right, the reporter doesn’t talk about several partitions for distribution. More over you need to support the proper partition key on the producer side for round-robin logic. The question is exactly about consumers.